# awk to print the fields based on condition:

Tags: awk

I would like to compare `first field and third filed` of Input.csv file with `Second and third fields` of Master.csv.
And if the `fruits name matches` and the Amount of Master.csv `is less than` Amount of Input.csv then print all the lines from both the files.

For example, 
`Fruits==Apple,Amount <20` from Master.csv need to be checked with Input.csv, so the output would be

```
Fruits,Region,Amount,Details
Apple,North,10,Abc
Apple,south,9,Abc
```

Input.csv

Fruits,Region,Amount,Details

```
Apple,North,10,Abc
Orange,East,115,Def
Apple,south,9,Abc
Apple,West,25,Abc
Orange,West,150,Def
Orange,North,200,Def
Mango,North,50,Ghi
Mango,East,75,Ghi
```

Master.csv

```
Details,Fruits,Amount
xxx,Apple,20
yyy,Mango,60
zzz,Cherry,80
```

Desired Output.csv

```
Fruits,Region,Amount,Details,Details,Fruits,Amount
Apple,North,10,Abc,xxx,Apple,20
Apple,south,9,Abc,xxx,Apple,20
Mango,North,50,Ghi,yyy,Mango,60
```

I have tried like below command

```
awk -F "," 'FNR==NR {a[$1]; b[$3]; next} $2 in a && $3 < b' Input.csv Master.csv > Output.csv
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following `awk` may help you on same:

```
awk -F"," 'FNR==1 && FNR==NR{val=$0} FNR==NR{a[$2]=$3;b[$2]=$0;next} FNR==1 && FNR!=NR{for(i=NF;i>0;i--){val1=val1?$i OFS val1:$i};print val,val1} (($1 in a) && $3<a[$1]){print $0,b[$1]}'  OFS=, master.csv input.csv
```

Adding a non-one liner form of solution now:

```
awk -F"," '
FNR==1 && FNR==NR{
  val=$0
}
FNR==NR{
  a[$2]=$3;
  b[$2]=$0;
  next
}
FNR==1 && FNR!=NR{
  for(i=NF;i>0;i--){
    val1=val1?$i OFS val1:$i};
  print val,val1
}
(($1 in a) && $3<a[$1]){
  print $0,b[$1]
}
'  OFS=, master.csv input.csv
```

Output will be as follows:

```
Details,Fruits,Amount,Fruits,Region,Amount,Details
Apple,North,10,Abc,xxx,Apple,20
Apple,south,9,Abc,xxx,Apple,20
Mango,North,50,Ghi,yyy,Mango,60
```

Comment: Thanks a lot RavinderSingh13 , while executing the command, i am getting the wrong header order

Comment: Details,Fruits,Amount,Fruits,Region,Amount,Details

Comment: It suppose to be :-  Fruits,Region,Amount,Details,Details,Fruits,Amount

Comment: @DEC, if your headings are fixed each time in Input_file(s) then we could simply print it, let me know if they are fixed?

Comment: Headers are not fixed , it vary

Comment: @DEC, please check my updated answer now and let me know if that helps, it is given as per your output only.

Comment: Thanks a lot RavinderSingh13 , I have accepted and Up-Voted the answer

Comment: @DEC, Glad that it helped you, you are yet to up-vote by the way :)

Comment: I did already , Seems that i should have 15 reputation to Up-Vote

Comment: @DEC, oh ok not an issue, keep learning and keep sharing enjoy this AWESOME site, tc